# crazy layout with GNOME 3 in Mint 14

Tags: linux-mint, gnome3, gnome-shell, window-decorations

I've installed GNOME 3 in Mint 14 with `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell` but now I have a problem. The general functionality is ok, but the windows look like the windows in Mint or rather like the windows in "GNOME (default) 2D":

[image]

And worse than that is the right-clicking-menu of the windows! For some reason my screenshot program is not able to make a screenshot of that menu.

And a second question: On [the Gnome extensions page](http://extensions.gnome.org) only 3 pages of extensions are available. Did I forget to install any packages?

**Update:**

I've also installed the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-session gnome-tweak-tool
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions gnome-shell-extensions-common
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, that your session does not start Mutter or Metacity, but uses Mint's default Muffin Window Manager instead.

You might need to change your session file, e.g. `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome.session` and set Mutter as your `DefaultProvider-windowmanager`, see [this link](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome) for instance:

Could you supply your process tree with `ps axjf`, so that we could see, what processes are started in your X session with what args? For instance, here is my gnomish fragment of `ps axjf` and note that I have `gnome-session` started with `--session gnome-fallback` and also `metacity` as window manager.

```
 /usr/sbin/gdm3
  \_ /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-simple-slave --display-id /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Display1
      \_ /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -verbose -novtswitch -auth /var/run/gdm3/auth-for-Debian-gdm-kcllLB/da
      \_ gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm3]
          \_ gnome-session --session gnome-fallback
              \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session-fallback
              \_ /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
              \_ /usr/bin/metacity
              \_ gnome-panel
              |   \_ iceweasel
              |   \_ gnome-terminal
              |       \_ gnome-pty-helper
              |       \_ bash
              |           \_ ps axjf
              \_ /usr/lib/gnome-disk-utility/gdu-notification-daemon
              \_ /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-miner-fs
              \_ /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-store
              \_ /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
              \_ gnome-screensaver
              \_ /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-fallback-mount-helper
              \_ bluetooth-applet
              \_ /usr/lib/evolution/3.4/evolution-alarm-notify
              \_ gnome-sound-applet
              \_ /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
              \_ nm-applet
```

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=103842) shows that there are a few packages more you need to install (gnome-session gnome-tweak-tool) then add one of the suggested PPAs for extensions.

Comment: It gives me the Error, that it couldn't find gnome-shell-extensions-common
...and nothing changed

Comment: Please don't name you link *this link* or *here*. Give it a useful name like *Linux Mint forum* or *Wikidpeia - FooBar*. Second: Please provide the gist of the information found on the page. In case the link dies this answer becomes obsolete as well.

Comment: @Jere: did you add the PPAs as suggested there? And performed an 'apt-get update'?

Comment: yes. and there were no errors...

Comment: @Marco Apologies; my edit introduced the generic link name when I uploaded the screenshot and I didn't change it.

Comment: OK now I installed all the packages.

But the problem is still the same :(

Comment: Log out and log in again.

Comment: :D I know. Nothing changed...